# Redis / Jedis - Tomcat hangs - - waiting on <5c1a77ba> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)

Tags: tomcat, redis, deadlock, jedis

I have got the following problem:

My Tomcat hangs with the following Thread Dump:

```
"ajp-bio-28109-exec-1589" - Thread t@1713
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
                at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
                - waiting on <5c1a77ba> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
                at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
                at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1118)
                at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:24)
```

My Application uses the Redis DB with Jedis Client. I have got about 2K requests / sec.
After some hours every Thread is waiting.

Could it be a DBCP issue?
Is there an other way to create a connection Pool with Redis / Jedis?

Thanks

Comment: Are you returning resources to the pool after using them? It seems like the pool is exhausted, as it is hanging in the "borrowObject" method.

Answer (score 3):

This was probably caused by using the default *whenExhaustedAction* setting which will block (invoke Object.wait()) until a new or idle object is available. check the javadoc [here](http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html).

You may need to increase your *maxActive* value or set a proper *maxWait*.

And as @xetorthio mentioned, You have to return jedis reources when done by:

```
Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
try {
  /// ... do stuff here ... for example
  jedis.set("foo", "bar");
  String foobar = jedis.get("foo");
  jedis.zadd("sose", 0, "car"); jedis.zadd("sose", 0, "bike"); 
  Set<String> sose = jedis.zrange("sose", 0, -1);
} finally {
  /// ... it's important to return the Jedis instance to the pool once you've finished using it
  pool.returnResource(jedis);
}
/// ... when closing your application:
pool.destroy();
```

Hope this helps.